# How to fix "*** [obj/flash_board_cstartup.o] Error 2"

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller

I am trying to get up to speed with the SAM7S examples pack "at91sam7s-ek" available from the Atmel website.

When I load any project into Eclipse I get the following error after building project.

```
make: *** [obj/flash_board_cstartup.o] Error 2
```

I have checked that paths are correct and that the files are where they are supposed to be.

Is there anyone that can help me to get this running or can anyone recommend a better set of examples that actually work for the SAM7S devices?

The CDT build console is :

```
18:58:29 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project test_project ****
make all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc -g -O0 -I../at91lib/boards/asn442g -I../at91lib/peripherals  -I../at91lib/components -I../at91lib -I. -I../at91lib/utility -I../external_libs/ethernet/lwip/src/include -I../external_libs/ethernet/lwip/src/include/lwip -I../external_libs/ethernet/lwip/src/include/ipv4 -I./system/modbus/tcp -I./system/modbus/tcp/arch -I./system/dal/dalAdc -I./system/dal/dalHoldingRegisters -I./system/dal/dalTimer -I./system/bll/bllModbusTCP -I./system/drivers/drvGprsLink -I./system/drivers/drvAtmBus -I./system/hal/halUsart1 -I./system/hal/halGpio -I./system/hal/halUsart0 -I./system/drv/drvAtmBus -Dat91sam7x256 -D__ASSEMBLY__ -Dflash -c -o obj/flash_board_cstartup.o ../at91lib/boards/asn442g/board_cstartup.S
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, arm-none-eabi-gcc -g -O0 -I../at91lib/boards/asn442g -I../at91lib/peripherals -I../at91lib/components -I../at91lib -I. -I../at91lib/utility -I../external_libs/ethernet/lwip/src/include -I../external_libs/ethernet/lwip/src/include/lwip -I../external_libs/ethernet/lwip/src/include/ipv4 -I./system/modbus/tcp -I./system/modbus/tcp/arch -I./system/dal/dalAdc -I./system/dal/dalHoldingRegisters -I./system/dal/dalTimer -I./system/bll/bllModbusTCP -I./system/drivers/drvGprsLink -I./system/drivers/drvAtmBus -I./system/hal/halUsart1 -I./system/hal/halGpio -I./system/hal/halUsart0 -I./system/drv/drvAtmBus -Dat91sam7x256 -D__ASSEMBLY__ -Dflash -c -o obj/flash_board_cstartup.o../at91lib/boards/asn442g/board_cstartup.S, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [obj/flash_board_cstartup.o] Error 2

18:58:33 Build Finished (took 3s.647ms)
```

Comment: When make return [Error *nn*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html), it means that a command that make has executed has returned a non-zero value *nn*.  Almost certainly the command that failed issued its own error message - that is what you need to post.  You are probably best posting the *entire* build log is you do not know what is relevant.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install or make available `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.

Comment: Good; but now surely you can see that in the title and the initial problem statement you are now emphasising the symptom rather than the problem!?  The failure occurs and is reported earlier in the log.  Read logs from top-down, not bottom-up; or in this case bottom-only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When make return [Error nn](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html), it means that a command that make has executed has returned a non-zero value nn. You need to look at the error message for teh command that failed, rather than teh final status of *make* - *make* has not failed; your build has failed.

In this case, the relevant error message (elided) is:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, arm-none-eabi-gcc  [...] obj/flash_board_cstartup.o
../at91lib/boards/asn442g/board_cstartup.S, ...) failed.
```

It appears on the face of it that the compiler  *arm-none-eabi-gcc* cannot be found.  Is it installed, and does the *PATH* environment variable include its location?

Comment: thank you very much dear Clifford . My problem was resolved after I installed again the gcc-arm-none-eabi.